# Is pairwise from itertools recipes always giving the same results as zip(a, a[1:])?

Tags: python

For quite a while I used the pairwise function from the itertools recipes. (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

But isn't that always giving the same result as zip(iterable, iterable[1:])?

Comment: slicing will cause most sequences to be evaluated, and produce another sequence.  Iterating doesn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zip(iterable, iterable[1:])` only works on things that can be sliced. `pairwise` works on arbitrary iterables.

To demonstrate, here’s an obscenely complex version of the typical functional infinite list (generator, here) of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def cons(x, xs):
    yield x
    yield from xs


def take(count, l):
    it = iter(l)

    for i in range(count):
        yield next(it)


def lazy_yield_from(get_iterable):
    yield from get_iterable()


infinite_fibonacci, _if = tee(
    cons(1, cons(1, lazy_yield_from(lambda: (a + b for a, b in pairwise(_if))))))

print(list(take(5, infinite_fibonacci)))
```

Comment: Wow this answer is really good. A 32 line demonstration to explain a one line answer :D